# Python only save the last parameter of a dict in a .txt file

Tags: python

I was trying to make a Login system but when i try to save the e-mail and password in a txt file
only save the last account created.
Like i put the e-mail and the password in a dict and put the dict in the file but everytime i create a new account,delete the other one

```
import json


def login(email, senha):
    with open("logins.txt") as file:
        contents = file.read()
    if email in contents and senha in contents:
        return True
        file.close()

return False
file.close()

def create_account():
    print('-' * 30)
    print(' \tCreate account.')
    print('-' * 30)

    email = input('Digite seu email:\n')
    password = input('Digite sua senha:\n')
    password_2 = input('Confirme sua senha:\n')
    if password == password_2:
        email = {email: password}
        with open("logins.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(json.dumps(email)+'\n')
        file.close()
        print('Account finish')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    enter = input('Login  /  Register\n')
    if enter == 'l':
        check_login = login(str(input('E-mail: ')), str(input('Password: ')))
    if check_login == True:
        print('-' * 10, 'Welcome', '-' * 10)
    else:
        print('Login not found!\n\n')
        create_account()

    if enter == 'r':
        print('\n\n')
        create_account()
```

#Sorry bad english

Comment: change the flie mode from `w` to `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the file in `write` mode, so it wipes all the previous data and writes the new data. Open it in `append` mode to solve this.

```
with open("logins.txt", "a") as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(email)+'\n')
file.close()
```

Also, you need not to close it as it is within `with` block

Answer (score 0):

try to change this line `with open("logins.txt", "w") as file:` to `with open("logins.txt", "a") as file:`

[Here](https://stackabuse.com/file-handling-in-python/) some extra information about access modes in python

Answer (score 0):

*Using the format 'w' will automatically overwrite everything inside the file, making it start blank.*  

If you only want to read something from your file, use the format 'r', which stands for read:

```
def login(email, senha):
    with open("logins.txt","r") as file:
        contents = file.read()
    if email in contents and senha in contents:
        return True
        file.close()
```

**If you only want to add something from your file, use the format 'a', which stands for append:**

```
def create_account():
    print('-' * 30)
    print(' \tCreate account.')
    print('-' * 30)

    email = input('Digite seu email:\n')
    password = input('Digite sua senha:\n')
    password_2 = input('Confirme sua senha:\n')
    if password == password_2:
        email = {email: password}
        with open("logins.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(json.dumps(email)+'\n')
        file.close()
        print('Account finish')
```

Answer (score 0):

because when you open a file in write mode with `w` `open("logins.txt", "w")`
the file seek pointer is set to zero so it starts writing from the start of the file
you want to open the file in append mode `open("logins.txt", "a")` to start writing from the end of file (EOF)

you can google to learn more about file seek pointers, different file modes (read, write, append) etc.